# How to set the background image for the particular button index of alert view in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to set a image at button index in UIAlertView. If it is possible then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you add imageview as a subview to alert view you can change its background, but only for a button in alert I guess it is not possible.

Have a look at this link. They are adding textfield as a subview to alertview:
[UITextView in UIAlertview not working in iOS 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612512/uitextview-in-uialertview-not-working-in-ios-4-x/9613409#9613409)